# Не получается использовать данные извлеченные из mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
if (!("firstName" in JSON.parse(chunk))) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(chunk));
    console.log("Ստացվել են մուտք գործելու տվյալները ֆռոնտից:");
    MongoClient.connect(mongo_url, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        let [users, loged_mail] = [db.db("registered_users_database"), { mail: JSON.parse(chunk).mail }];
        users.collection("registered_users_collection").findOne(loged_mail, (err, result) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result);
            console.log(`Գրանցված օգտատերն է ${result.firstName}ը։`);
            db.close();
        });
    });
    res.end("something");
}
```

Хочу передать result внешней переменной (объекту), чтобы потом использовать. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: внешняяПеременная = result;

Comment: Так просто не получается....

Comment: тогда уточните, что, как,  где, когда - не получается. И код поправьте - уберите все, что не относиться к проблеме

Comment: Извлеченные данные из базы нужно сохранить в глобальной переменной, для дальнейшего использования...

Comment: ну так сохраняйте. В каком месте кода, Вы это пытаетесь сделать и у Вас не получается?

Comment: после присваивания выдаст undefined.